# Stacking modals with translucent backgrounds shows abnormal background with brighter corners

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, vue.js

I have an absolutely positioned modal with a translucent background on top of another modal that also has a translucent background. Normally, the background now should be slightly darker as the two translucent backgrounds are overlapping.

However, I get a very strange result, where the the corners are brighter than the the parts in the middle.

[image]

I am using Vuejs framework and the top-most modal is inside the template of the modal right underneath it. In other words, the top-most modal is a child of the modal underneath it.

When I am showing this modal without another modal behind it, it has a normal background (uniformly translucent, without dark and light parts as shown).

Really, confused by this behaviour. What could be wrong, and how could I fix this?

**EDIT**

I was wrong about the modal underneath being absolutely positioned. It was actually fixed positioned, and changing the bottom modal to absolutely positioned solved this problem.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Ok so I was wrong about the modal underneath being absolutely positioned. It was actually fixed position which for some reason caused this. Changing the position of the modal underneath to absolute, it solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the position of the bottom modal to absolute solved this issue.